# Adding area column using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to compute the areas of the new layer I created by intersecting two layers.

How can I write a script that does something equivalent to clicking Export/Add geometry columns?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()

areas = [ feat.geometry().area() 
          for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

field = QgsField("area", QVariant.Double)
provider.addAttributes([field])
layer.updateFields()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('area')

for area in areas:
    new_values = {idx : float(area)}
    provider.changeAttributeValues({areas.index(area):new_values})
```

It works for me. I tried it out in this situation:

[image]

The field 'area' was added after running the code at the Python Console of QGIS.