# provider.addAttribute $area

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to add the attribute `$area`. I made a intersection and `Tot_aera` isn't the good one, so I want to add a new.

I made that :

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
try:
    if ind==-1:
        if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
            res=provider.addAttributes( [ QgsField(nameattr,QVariant.Double) ] )
except:
    print "FALSE"
```

So I have a new attribute but `NULL`. So my question : How put `"$area"` in nameattr?

Comment: Hi, `addAttribute` only creates a new field, it doesn't fill it. I suggest you have a look at this post: [Add area column using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168661/add-area-column-using-pyqgis).