# Calculating weighted values using function in Function Editor

Tags: qgis, python, attribute-table, function, calculate-values

After my previous question [Weighted values of field in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301639/weighted-values-of-the-field-in-qgis), I successfully adapted the following formula in Expression dialogue

```
"Value" / (sum("Value") / (count(CASE WHEN "Value" >= 1 THEN +1 END)))
```

In QGIS in the Attribute Table, there are many fields with values for which I count using this formula.

However, I don't want to repeat all long action and therefore I need to create a function in the Function editor. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function in the `'Function Editor'`.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')

def calculate_values(value, feature, parent):
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    sum_values = sum(filter(None,[f['Value'] for f in layer.getFeatures()]))
    count_value = sum(1 for x in filter(None,[f['Value'] for f in layer.getFeatures()]))
    if value:
        return float(value)/sum_values/count_value
    else:
        return NULL
```

The result of the function will give a desired output.

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Adding area column using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168661/adding-area-column-using-pyqgis)
- [Summing field values with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313901/summing-field-values-with-pyqgis)